# Test function with multiple raw inputs from a user

Tags: python, user-input

I need to test a function, similar to below, to check the prompts, and output, from the function.  As you can see, there is some branching.  My ideal goal is to be able to specify the values I want to try in the function, but also capture all of the output text along the way.

```
def prompt():
  guess = input("guess a letter: ")
  return(guess)


def testme():
    i = 1
    vocab = ['a', 'b', 'c','d', 'e', 'f']
    import random
    correct = random.choice(vocab)
    while i < 4:
        i = i + 1 
        guess = prompt()
        if correct == guess:
            print("Well done!")
            i = 100
        else:
          print("Wrong!\n")

testme()
```

**My need:**

It's worth noting that you can see my function `test` intentionally does not take any arguments, but rather, is a function where the user has to interface with the prompts.  I need to automate this part, and capture how the function reacts (the messages sent to the console) until the function ends.

I am trying to avoid manually running through this by hand to see if the function behaves the way I expect given the fact that the user can provide multiple inputs.

Comment: You could comment out ```guess = input("guess a letter: ")``` temporarly and use ```alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e']``` and ```guess = random.choice(alphabets)```

Comment: I updated the question above to hopefully clearly articulate my need.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take an argument and pass the list to it:

```
def testme(vocab):
    i = 1
    import random
    correct = random.choice(vocab)
    while i < 4:
        i = i + 1 
        guess = prompt()
        if correct == guess:
            print("Well done!")
            i = 100
        else:
          print("Wrong!\n")
```

And call it like:

```
testme(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

Also you can take comma delimited values from user, split them and convert to list and pass to the function.

Comment: Thanks, I added notes to the original question above.  This function does not have inputs, and requires the user interact with it on the command line.  I don't want to test this function by hand but rather automate the inputs and capture the functions responses until it ends.  A true automated test.  I have 100 students and am trying to avoid this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by capturing the output? Do you want to save what the user typed? Do you want to see how many guesses it took?
I think you could take a look at the for loop and the break statement :) they will make your work easier

```
def prompt():
  guess = input("guess a letter: ")
  return(guess)


def testme(vocab):
    import random
    correct = random.choice(vocab)
    for i in range(4):
        guess = prompt()
        if correct == guess:
            print("Well done!")
            break
        else:
          print("Wrong!\n")
    return my_list_of_outputs

testme(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

Comment: If you run through this code, you see that there is feedback, guess again, you were correct and the loop stops, etc.  I need to automate how I test the results of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated above to clarify that my function intentionally does not take input.  Instead of using the command line as the function is running, I need to automate the inputs and capture/save the functions responses to the user.